# Confusion with iframe api

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api

Heyo guys!

I am new to javascript and kind of a noob,
That's why I try to use as less js as possible but for this part i really needed it.

I have a fullscreen video and it plays correctly the first time, but I want it to use the Embedded URL again when it reloads. So I made this js.

```
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          var player;
          player = new YT.Player('video', {
            videoId: 'A3rvUNcueFg', // YouTube Video ID
            playerVars: {
              autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
              controls: 0,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
              showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
              loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
              fs: 1,              // Hide the full screen button
              cc_load_policty: 0, // Hide closed captions
              iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
              autohide: 1,         // Hide video controls when playing
              start: 13,
              end: 295,
              rel: 0,
              playlist: 'A3rvUNcueFg'
            },
            events: {
              onReady: function(e) {
                e.target.mute();
                var Embed = e.target.getVideoEmbedCode();
              }
            }
          });
          YT.PlayerState.ENDED: function(e) {
            var player;
            player = new YT.Player(Embed)
         }
```

So what I want it to do, I want it to mute (that part works).
Then get the embed URL so i can use it to reload the video at the same start point after it ended. Because it now reloads and starts at the beginning.

Thanks in advance,
Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

How about including the seekTo option in your video object. You can pass it the number of seconds that you want to skip to start the video at.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      var player;
      var time = //whatever time you want it to start from each loop; NEW CODE
      player = new YT.Player('video', {
        videoId: 'A3rvUNcueFg', // YouTube Video ID
        playerVars: {
          autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
          controls: 0,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
          showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
          loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
          fs: 1,   // Hide the full screen button
          cc_load_policty: 0, // Hide closed captions
          iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
          autohide: 1,         // Hide video controls when playing
          start: 13,
          end: 295,
          rel: 0,
          playlist: 'A3rvUNcueFg'
        },
        events: {
          onReady: function(e) {
            e.target.mute();
            var Embed = e.target.getVideoEmbedCode();
          }
        }
      });
      YT.PlayerState.ENDED: function(e) {
        var player;
        player = new YT.Player(Embed);
        player.seekTo(time);  //NEW CODE
     }
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls

player.seekTo(seconds:Number, allowSeekAhead:Boolean):Void